# ¿Como reproducir un vídeo de youtube con el URL en WUP O WPF? c# visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, youtube, stream

Buen día, me encuentro tratando de reproducir un vídeo de youtube en visual studio c#, sinceramente llevo todo el día y solo he encontrado información muy antigua (2013 hacia atrás y muchas cosas que no funcionan), la primera es utilizando la libreria Mytoolkit junto con el componente "MediaElement" y utilizando el siguiente código

```
 private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uri _videoUri = await GetYoutubeUri("OgO4v6W72YY");
        if (_videoUri != null)
        {
            player.Source = _videoUri;
            player.Play();
        }
    }


    internal async Task<Uri> GetYoutubeUri(string VideoID)
    {
        YouTubeUri uri = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(VideoID, YouTubeQuality.Quality1080P);
        return uri.Uri;
    }
```

Y este es el .xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <MediaElement x:Name="Reproductor" LoadedBehavior="Manual" ></MediaElement>


    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="419,275,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

Se supone que eso debiera ser suficiente pero me da el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que entiendo normalmente este error se debe a que no hay una referencia a un objeto pero no creo que sea eso ya que cuando envió una url de un vídeo diferente a alguno de Youtube este se reproduce si problemas, ejemplo:

```
 private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri _videoUri = await GetYoutubeUri("OgO4v6W72YY");
        if (_videoUri != null)
        {
            /*Uri directa*/
             Reproductor.Source = new Uri("http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4");
            //Reproductor.Source = _videoUri;
            Reproductor.Play();
        }
    }

    internal async Task<Uri> GetYoutubeUri(string VideoID)
    {
        YouTubeUri uri = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(VideoID, YouTubeQuality.Quality1080P);
        return uri.Uri;
    }
```

Espero me puedan ayudar con este dilema, gracias

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probablemente la respuesta que te voy a dar no te va a gustar, pero es lo que hay.

El problema no está en tu código, sino en que `MediaElement` tiene problemas para reproducir medios en servidores seguros (`https`). Si te fijas en el ejemplo que pones que si funciona, el enlace es sobre `http`.

Al parecer existió un bug report (que ha desparecido, o no consigo encontrarlo) sobre el tema que se cerró indicando que no se iba a resolver.

La única solución si quieres seguir usando `MediaElement` es descargar el vídeo a local y reproducirlo desde ahí. A continuación te pongo un ejemplo:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Uri _videoUri = await GetYoutubeUri("1uP7AMW9bXg");
    if (_videoUri != null)
    {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            //descargamos el vídeo a la carpeta donde se ejecuta la app como "video.mp4"
            wc.DownloadFile(_videoUri, System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "video.mp4"));
        }
        // Ponemos como fuente el vídeo recién descargado
        Reproductor.Source = new Uri(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "video.mp4"));
        Reproductor.Play();
    }
}
```

P.D. El código del vídeo de youtube que pones como ejemplo (`OgO4v6W72YY`) devuelve `forbidden`, es posible que sea de VeVo o con alguna restricción de reproducción.

P.D.2 En mi experiencia, tratar de reproducir vídeos de YouTube de una forma externa a su propio reproductor solo lleva a frustración. Google trata de evitarlo por todas las maneras, y cada poco tiempo cambian cosas para que lo que antes te funcionaba, ya no lo haga. Tienen multitud de restricciones por pais,dispositivo, etc... que te harán la vida muy difícil.

Comment: Gracias, alfinal voy a terminar utilizando el WebBroswer